# username.github.io pages not published as github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I have Created the repository named as username.github.io and tried to access the same URL in browser but i'm getting 404 error.

Checked in repository settings -> Under Github Pages Section, But it was not showing the message "your site is published at username.github.io"

Apart from this, is there anything i have to do...

**Screenshot:**
[image]
**Actual URL:** https://username.github.io

Answer (score 3):

To create a GitHub Pages site for your own username (i.e. a personal website and not a website for a repository), you need to replace the `username` part of `username.github.io` with your GitHub username. For example, if my username on GitHub is `abcde`, I would create a repository called `abcde.github.io` and then enable GitHub Pages in its settings as you have done.

Comment: `safinghoghabori.github.io` i changed my repository name like this, it changed the URL but not showing anything when i visit that URL.

Comment: Did you enable GitHub pages in the settings for the repository? Also, sometimes you may need to specify the branch to use for the website.

Also keep in mind that the first time you set up GitHub pages it may take some time to generate.

Comment: yes i did. But i want my portfolio website to run at `safinghoghabori.github.io` not at `safinghoghabori.github.io/dir-name`. So how can i do that?

Comment: Did you set up an index.html file?

Answer (score 1):

You need select source branch to publish(Initially it will be none. So nothing published) in
 `Settings -> Github pages --> source` and click `save`. Then only it will be published to username.github.io URL.

Make sure your branch has index.html file.

Comment: do you have index.html file in master branch?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, github pages URLs are generated as **username.github.io/repo-name**.

I'm not sure what naming the repo as you did would do, but in most cases, just name the repo as you normally would (a description of the project) and then publish the sites that way. If you already have code, here is how to [rename the project](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-to-do-I-rename-my-repo/td-p/217) in Github and [updating the remote url](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/)

I'm not sure exactly why your pages aren't generating, but it likely has to do with the name of your repo.

Comment: In this case, it seems that the aim is to create a GitHub Pages site for the user, not for the repository, in which case the name [username].github.io is what is required for the repository name.